# jquery files selector conflicting

Tags: jquery

I am using two libraries of jQuery. One is main library from site(I named it as mainlibrary.js) other as limitkeypress.js(named as same). I think both files are conflicting.  I used code in sadd.php at line 24 as

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$.noConflict(); 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#title").limitkeypress ({ rexp:/^[A-Za-z.\-\s]*$/ });
});
</script>
```

I got chrome error as

- limitkeypress.js:125 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
  (anonymous function)
- sadd.php:24 Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function (anonymous function)

Where as my limitkeypress file at line 125 end with code.. **})(jQuery);**

Firefox extension firebug issues same error as..

- $ is not a function
- sadd.php().                 sadd.php (line 24)
- $(document).ready(function() {

What should I do in order avoid this error permanently. I mean if I use any other library. I won't have this error further.

Comment: Why do you think they are conflicting?  You shouldn't call `noConflict` since `limitkeypress` is just a plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

You use `$.noConflict()`, which unbinds `$`, then try to use it on the next line. `jQuery` should be available, if you're loading jQuery.

Comment: You can also give jQuery a different shortcut like var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); and then use $j.

Comment: @RahulSingh He did. Call $.noConflict() and then just use the name jQuery instead of $.

Comment: What should I do if I want to use $ at place of jQuery

Comment: @RahulSingh Don't use `noConflict`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading two versions of jquery you should have extra care because you need to use noconflict before loading the other. Look at [this](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/) article an this example

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.1.3 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dimensions.min.js"></script>

<!-- revert global jQuery and $ variables and store jQuery in a new variable -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.3.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

<!-- revert global jQuery and $ variables and store jQuery in a new variable -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

If you just want to use `$` instead of `jQuery`, don't call noConflict

Comment: @Nicole: can you join me on gotomeeting.com, I would be able to show you my code.

Comment: Can you take me to the chat..?